# The requested URL was not found on this server. - php, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following folder structure on my local -

```
xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mdbblog
```

on my local and under this directory, have following files -

[image]

I activated `mdblog` theme from `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/` and able to access the index page of my site `http://localhost/wordpress`.

The problem is I am unable to href any other page from home page.Following is my code to access Gallery in the menu -

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="nav-link" style="padding:5px 10px;" href="./clinic-gallery-page.php">Clinic </a>
              <a class="nav-link" style="padding:5px 10px;" href="patients-gallery-page.php">Patients</a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

When I click `Clinic`, I get following error - 
 [image]

I have no clue as what am I doing wrong here. I new to PHP and Wordpress. I also don't see any pages present under `mdblog` theme on admin. Is that expected? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sooo WordPress isn't exactly a file request type system....   WordPress will only resolve based on your db...  Read te docs or ask more direct questions.   I advise you:

1. Create a page. .. this pages will register a route (sortoff) on your db
2. Assign that page to your menu

Big warning. When you create a localhost page on development, this will be written like that on your db.  When you take this to a production server, you will end up with some links as localhost and some as the domain.    U will either always have to redirect, or before you upload your db to production, you can dump the sql, and do a find localhost and replace with your new domain   on notepad ++

Unless you are creating your own theme. I wouldn't add files directly to your theme as it can be overwritten on an update. Create a plugin.